Accessing SQLite 3 database in Angular Service Module
I'm not a new developer, but I'm new to VSCode and Angular. I'm working with a UDemy course to learn Angular and the course uses the browser "localStorage" object to save and retrieve data information. This works fine for training, but I need to use a SQLite database.
I'm trying to convert over from the localStorage to using a database created in SQLite. I will eventually create an Angular app to use an existing SQLite database, so changing databases is not an option.
I know that database connections must be done in a service module, which makes sense. I ran the terminal statement: "npm i sqlite3" and then added the import statement
"import { sqlite3 } from 'sqlite3' 

at the top of my service module. Then in the constructor, I have the statement:
"const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose(); 

Everything looks fine until I compile, then I get a compiler error:
"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in C:\Users\pain\myapp\node_modules\sqlite3\lib'

I don't even know how 'util' has anything to do with anything.
Whatever help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Perhaps I'm missing an import or something in one of the other code files.

That's a nose package. You can't run sqlite natively in the browser. You'll need a wasm package or have a node server.

What is a wasm package. Sounds like I need to add something else. Do you have a specific one that you suggest?

For starters.
